Why Vue's vue-test-utils test unit does not reach the proper route when using clicking a button?
I'm trying to write test for a form submission and no matter what I tried it failed.
I was able to reduce the problem to a and App (App.vue), 2 components (TroubledLogin.vue and Info.vue) and a test unit (login.test.js).
So the problem is that if I try to test the click (inside TroubledLogin) with test unit the router does not change the current route. Is as if the click is triggered but test unit does not "wait" for the navigator to reach the new route. (Node: I simulated the http/axios request API with fakelogin)
The exact code that "hangs" is this:
async login() {
    console.info("Login button pressed");
    this.status = 1; //loading
    
    //If I uncomment next line the test will fail
    // const response = await this.fakelogin(this.input.username, this.input.password);

    await this.$router.push("/info");
    this.status = 0; //default
}

What is wrong with this approach?
Bellow is the detailed code:
TroubledLogin.vue
<template>
    <div id="login">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Login</h1>
        <form class="form">
            <label class="form-label" for="username">Username</label>
            <br/>
            <input class="form-field" type="text" name="username" v-model="input.username" placeholder="Username" />
            <br/>        
            <label class="form-label" for="password">Password</label>
            <br/>
            <input class="form-field" type="password" name="password" v-model="input.password" placeholder="Password" />
            <br/>
            <div style="text-align: center;" >
                <button class="form-field" type="button" @click="login()" value="Login">Login</button>
            </div>
            
            <br/>
            <span v-if="status==1">Authenticating...</span>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
    name: 'TroubledLogin',
    components: {
    },
    data() {
        return {
            input: {
                password: '',
                username: '',                
            },
            status: 0,
        };
    },
    methods: {
        /**Just a slow method to simulate HTTP calls*/
        async fakelogin(userName, password) {
            return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    resolve('Whatever')
                }, 1000)
            })
        },

        async login() {
            console.info("Login button pressed");
            this.status = 1; //loading
            
            //If I uncomment next line the test will fail
            // const response = await this.fakelogin(this.input.username, this.input.password);

            await this.$router.push("/info");
            this.status = 0; //default
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>

login.test.js
import { describe, expect, test } from 'vitest'
import { mount, flushPromises } from '@vue/test-utils'
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import App from '@/App.vue'
import TroubledLogin from "@/views/TroubledLogin.vue"
import Info from "@/views/Info.vue"



const routes = [
    {
      path: "/troubledlogin",
      name: "troubledlogin",
      component: TroubledLogin
    },
    {
      path: "/info",
      name: "info",
      component: Info
    }
  ]

describe('Login', () => {
    
    test('submit the form', async () => {
        const router = createRouter({
            history: createWebHistory(),
            routes: routes,
        })

        let step = 1;

        router.push("/troubledlogin")
        await router.isReady();
        console.log(`${step++}. Current route: ${router.currentRoute.fullPath}` )
        

        const wrapper = mount(App, {
            global: {
                plugins: [router],                    
            },
        }) 

        await flushPromises();

        console.log(`${step++}. Current route: ${wrapper.vm.$route.fullPath}` )


        //@see https://test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html
        let username = wrapper.find("input[name=username]")
        await username.setValue('test')
        expect(username.element.value).toBe('test')

        let password = wrapper.find("input[type=password]")
        await password.setValue('test1234')
        expect(password.element.value).toBe('test1234')

        let button = wrapper.find('button');
        console.info(`${step++}. Submit button value: ` + button.element.value)
        await button.trigger('click')

        await router.isReady();
        await flushPromises();

        console.log(`${step++}. Current route: ${wrapper.vm.$route.fullPath}` )

        expect(`${wrapper.vm.$route.fullPath}`).to.be.equal('/info')
    })
    
})

Info.vue
<template>
    Info about App
</template>

<script>


export default {
    name: 'Info',
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>

App.vue
<template>
    <main>              
        <router-view></router-view>
    </main>
</template>

<script>
import { RouterView } from 'vue-router';


export default {
    name: "App",
    data() {
        return {
        }
    },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>


pakage.json looks like
{
  "name": "commander",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test": "vitest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@imengyu/vue3-context-menu": "^1.3.5",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.4.5",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "jenesius-vue-modal": "^1.10.3",
    "test-utils": "^1.1.1",
    "vitest": "^1.4.0",
    "vue": "^3.3.10",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.5.1",
    "jsdom": "^24.0.0",
    "vite": "^5.0.5"
  }
}



The only solution I found to work is simply to give some time for the navigator/jsdom to load new page - so it's basically a hack.
So it's a matter of adding a sleep
const sleep = (ms) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

and then use it in the test unit
console.info(`${step++}. Submit button value: ` + button.element.value)
await button.trigger('click')

await sleep(1000); //<-- Add this line

await router.isReady();

So unless there is a better way to control or observe the navigator (page change) this is the only way to achieve the result.
